# How to post a list in django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried to get this:

**output**

```
{
    "counter": 2,
    "items": ["a", "a", "b", "c"]
}
```

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    counter = models.ForeignKey(Counter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='stocks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stock)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.ListField()
    counter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Counter.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['counter', 'items']
```

but I got this error:

**error**

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `items` on serializer `OrderSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Order` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Order' object has no attribute 'items'.
```

Should I create a variable in models.py called "items" because I tried it doesn't work either?

Comment: What does your `Order` model look like?

Comment: I've added it sorry

Comment: 'Order' object has no attribute 'items'.

Comment: Thanks I change my model. I deleted "stock" variable and added "items" variable but how should I do to connect element in list with my stock ?

Comment: Use a PrimaryKeyRelatedField with many=True and queryset set.

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    counter = models.ForeignKey(Counter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.counter)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.ListField()
    counter = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Counter.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['counter', 'items']
```

when I try to POST a list:

```
{
    "counter": 1,
    "items": ["a","b"]
}
```

I got this:

```
[
    {
        "counter": 1,
        "items": [
            "[",
            "'",
            "a",
            "'",
            ",",
            " ",
            "'",
            "b",
            "'",
            "]"
        ]
    }
]
```

Do you know where the problem come from ?

Comment: Maybe you can try `JSONField`: `items = models.JSONField()`

Comment: Seems like a problem on the client side. So, show the client side code.

Comment: Thanks Georgine, it works but when I want to get a detail like "orders/1" I get : "detail": "Not found."